# SQL Server Convert 01 December 2016 to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, sql-convert

How can one convert the string "01 December 2016" to a date type in SQL Server?

```
CONVERT(date, '01 December 2016', 106)
```

Expected date outcome "01 Dec 2016"

Comment: Your code works.  SQL Server (correctly) returns 2016-12-01, because that is the format for returning dates.  If you want a different format, then use `convert(varchar())` with the appropriate format argument.  Or `format()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If 2012+ you can use Format()

```
Select Format(convert(date,'01 December 2016'),'dd MMM yyyy')
```

Returns

```
01 Dec 2016
```

Comment: Calling `CONVERT` like above means to rely on implicit culture/language conversions. On my system this would break. +1 for the `FORMAT()`

Answer (score 1):

It is very dangerous to work with culture specific date/time formats and it is even worse to work with language and culture specific formats...

If ever possible **store date/time values in appropriate types!**

In my (german) system a direct cast or convert would break due to "December", which is "Dezember" in Germany. Have a look at this:

```
SET LANGUAGE English; --try the same with "German"

DECLARE @d VARCHAR(100)='01 December 2016';

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),CONVERT(DATE,@d,106),106);
```

The result

```
01 Dec 2016
```

One should never rely on implicit conversions: [Call `CONVERT` with the third parameter in any case!](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql)

The third parameter `106` tells SQL Server the date's format (how to parse it). The first `CONVERTS`s target type is `DATE`. This - now properly represented! - date can be converted again to `VARCHAR(11)` with 106 as third parameter now specifying the **output format**.

For deeper insight in language specific date parts you can run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.syslanguages;
```

### btw: If you are using SQL Server 2012+ you should call `FORMAT()` as pointed out by John Cappelletti

Comment: Even safer.  To my shame I tend to be rather insensitive to such itemes  +1